# This tag should be [subject]ed to burnination

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subject) tag has no tag wiki, and its [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subject) are a hodgepodge of questions about Angular [Subject](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1)s and other topics, including the "subject" line of various messaging protocols.

Can we [subject] this tag to extreme burnination? Perhaps the questions about Angular Subjects could be retagged [angular-subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-subject).

Comment: Scrolling through the top voted questions, the majority seem to be referring to the email subject line, which doesn't seem like a valid or useful tag

Answer (score 6):

Angular only appears to be a small subset of the tag, however. [156 are not tagged Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subject+-angular+-angular6+-angular5)

As for the remaining criteria

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   Nope. There's email subject, Android PushSubject, Spreadsheet subject. The usages are very... [subject]ive
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Kinda. Generating a subject is on-topic but we don't need a tag for that
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Not really. This is a meta tag.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Angular Subject vs email subject vs [whatever subject they're talking about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529169/error-takeuntil-is-not-a-function-on-all-my-observables). Very disjointed

So this seems to be a solid candidate for burnination.